Unable to download physical file in Razor Pages
I have a physical file that I want the user to be able to download. The file is in the same folder as my current Razor Page. Here's what I've tried.
First Method: Page Handler
Markup
<a asp-page-handler="DownloadHelp" title="Template Help"><img src="~/images/help.png" /></a>

Code
public IActionResult OnGetDownloadHelp(
{
    return File("TemplateHelp.pdf", MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}

Result
I get an error that says TemplateHelp.pdf was not found. Strangely, the exception stops on the line await next.Invoke(context); in one of my middleware classes. I'm not sure why the exception appears to be occurring there.
Second Method: Markup Only
Markup
<a download href="TemplateHelp.pdf" title="Download Template Documentation"><img src="~/images/help.png" /></a>

Result
The filename appears in the list of downloads but says Couldn't download - No file.

This seems like it should be straight forward. Does anyone know how to do this?

put in special "wwwroot" folder and use href="~/TemplateHelp.pdf".  No need to use a controller if you don't need to protect the file from deep-links.   If you do want to ensure the download is authorized, you'd put this file in a folder where only a controller can get it, then have the controller check for authorization/authentication and then return File.  (ex: AppContext.BaseDirectory + "/PDFs/TemplateHelp.pdf")  File can take memorystream, filestream, etc...

By default, only files in the wwwroot folder are accessible via a direct request.
From comprehension of the MS document, Razor Pages are primarily used to handle dynamic content, while static content (like PDF) should be served from the wwwroot directory unless special routing or middleware are configured.
The design is intended to protect application code and other non-static files from being exposed. Files outside of wwwroot are not automatically accessible via URL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Could try PageContext.HttpContext.Request.Path to get the current path.

The file needs to be in the path of the static files (usually wwwroot), this is the place where asp.net searches for static files and can serve them to the client.

Thanks, but as explained, that isn't where my file is. What do you mean this is where ASP.NET searches for static files? For which operation? The method I'm using takes a complete path. It shouldn't be looking in wwwroot.

When you publish your app, the wwwroot folder is copied to the build output folder. The static file middleware will return those files when the url matches. Everything else is source code which is compiled into assemblies. You don't want your .cs or .cshtml files to be downloadable. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@JeremyLakeman: Good point. Thanks.

Where is your file being stored in your application? In cases like this, it is better to specify the full path of the file being downloaded. Maybe the error is because the application couldn't find the file specified?
The code should look like this:
public IActionResult OnGetDownloadHelp()
{
  byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("your_path_to_the_file.pdf");
  var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositon();
  contentDisposition.Inline = false;
  Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
  return File(file,"application/pdf");
}

The inline parameter can automatically download/not download the file in your local system depending on its value. True for not automatic download, and false for automatic download.
I hope this helps!

As I explained, the file is in the same folder that contains the Razor Page that is accessing it. But the whole point is that I don't know the exact path on the server. And even if I could determine this, I would never hard code the path because it could be a different path on a different server if I ever had to move it.

If that's the case, is a database also involved in your application? Because then you could store the file there and put a reference inside the action
